# Where can I find FPDF? "FPDF error: Some data has already been output..."

Tags: wordpress, pdf, woocommerce, fpdf

Where is FPDF?  I use Wordpress and Go Daddy, I am trying to use this WooCommerce PDF Watermark, and I am getting a fatal error that causes the watermark not to be visible.

The error is below, how can I fix this?

Notice: iconv(): Wrong charset, conversion from `UTF-8' to` ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT' is not allowed in /var/www/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-pdf-watermark/includes/class-wc-pdf-watermarker.php on line 128

Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file in /var/www/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-pdf-watermark/includes/lib/fpdf/fpdf.php:292 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-pdf-watermark/includes/lib/fpdf/fpdf.php(1081): FPDF->Error('Some data has a...') #1 /var/www/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-pdf-watermark/includes/lib/fpdf/fpdf.php(1020): FPDF->_checkoutput() #2 /var/www/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-pdf-watermark/includes/class-wc-pdf-watermarker.php(521): FPDF->Output() #3 /var/www/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-pdf-watermark/includes/class-wc-pdf-watermark.php(610): WC_PDF_Watermarker->watermark(NULL, NULL, '/var/www/wp-con...', NULL, true) #4 /var/www/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(303): WC_PDF_Watermark->maybe_render_preview('') #5 /var/www/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(327): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #6 /var/www/wp-includes/plugin.php(470): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #7 /var/www/wp-admin/admin.php(175): do_action('admin_init') #8 {m in /var/www/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-pdf-watermark/includes/lib/fpdf/fpdf.php on line 292

Answer (score 0):

The server hosting your WordPress site must have the PHP class [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) installed.
It is generating PDF files free of charge.

That class is one of the [requirements](https://woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-pdf-watermark/#section-1) of the Plugin "WooCommerce PDF Watermark".

See if you can install it at Go Daddy.
For instance by making FPDF a Composer requirement, if you can use Composer with your hosting package.